this.videoStream = await (0, puppeteer_stream_1.getStream)(this.page, this.config.streamConfig) not working when the function is called second time
this.videoStream = await (0, puppeteer_stream_1.getStream)(this.page, this.config.streamConfig);

My code using puppeteer stream to stream browser audio and video into .mp4 file.
This line of code seems to be working when I am invoking the function for the first time. However when I invoke the function the second time, I see the following error
ProtocolError: Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Promise was collected
I am destroying the video stream after the function call but I still keep getting the error. Can anyone help me with this ?
 setTimeout(async () => {
            await this.videoStream.destroy();
            this.videoStream.unpipe(this.videoFileStream.stdin);
            console.log("finished");
            await this.videoFileStream.destroy();
            await this.browser.close();
        }, 1000 * 10);
    ```
    It works fine when I restart the my index.js


Please share a complete, runnable [mcve]. What are you trying to accomplish exactly? Looks like you're closing the browser in the timeout loop, which may explain why it only works the first time. Generally, since you're in async/await code, don't use async callbacks, use import {setTimeout} from "node:timers/promises" and use await setTimeout(1000).
